# How long does it take for a badge to be awarded?

Tags: support, badges

I recently completed 1000 reviews under the "Suggested Edits" category, but the badge has not been awarded yet.

[image]

How long should users expect to wait for a badge to show up?

Comment: And yes, I am aware that [we don't need no stinking badges!](https://youtu.be/VqomZQMZQCQ?t=3)

Comment: Congratulations on your first gold badge!

Comment: @Scott You mean my tenth? :)

Comment: D'oh! I was looking at your Meta profile.  Well, congratulations anyway.  In case you hadn't noticed, you seem to have it now.

Comment: I figured it would be a few hours or something, but I was surprised that no one has asked this yet

Comment: Meta-questions that are not specifically about one community (e.g., tags, on-topic rules, etc.) tend to gravitate toward [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com), where you can find [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1716/195817), [“Where's the badge I just earned?”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167524/195817), and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/135565), depending on whether the unicorn gets lost. GPS is so unreliable these days.

More seriously? I believe there's a daily task that runs for things like this, so you should see it in a day or two.